# Strange destructor behavior, called twice, but skip code execution for the first time

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, destructor

To simplify things let's say I have simple class definition within destructor inside

```
public class MyDisposeFinalize
{
    ~MyDisposeFinalize()
    {
        var breakPoint = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In the `Main` method I first create instance of `MyDisposeFinalize` class, then assign `null` to my instance and call for garbage collection.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDispose = new MyDisposeFinalize();
        myDispose = null;
        GC.Collect();

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I expect that my destructor will be called one time, when finalization thread process finalization queue.

In fact, when I put break point inside my destructor method on entry, inside and exit I have really strange behavior:

1. Entry break point is hit
2. Then again entry break point is hit
3. Inside break point is hit
4. Exit break point is hit
5. Then again entry break point is hit

The first idea was that two different threads come to execute destructor method, but then why does one of them skip method code and only execute it on second iteration? And in general why does desctructor is being called twice?

Comment: What do you mean by "a break point inside my destructor on entry"? I never put any breakpoint before the first statement of a method. Putting a breakpoint on the prototype of a method is meaningless and is compiler-ide dependent.

Comment: I think I get it now - The OP is putting a breakpoint on the curly braces before and after the line of code.

Comment: @AhmadWabbi Yes, I put breakpoint on entry curly braces, inside method and on exit curly braces.

Comment: @Baldrick I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, this is regular Console application

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov - I can repeat your findings using 4.5.2 Console as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you open your code in ILSpy, you'll see this:

```
protected override void Finalize()
{
    try
    {
        string breakPoint = string.Empty;
    }
    finally
    {
        base.Finalize();
    }
}
```

I expect that by breaking on the open and close braces, you're seeing multiple 'lines of code' executing, which are occurring linked to the line of code associated with the open and close braces. i.e. the `try` and the `base.Finalize()` call.

In raw IL, the end part of the code looks like this:

```
finally
{
    IL_000a: ldarg.0
    IL_000b: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::Finalize()
    IL_0010: nop
    IL_0011: endfinally
} //
```

It makes a call to Object::Finalize(), which might be where your breakpoint is stopping a second time.

I'm not sure what the expected behavior is of putting breakpoints there, but I think that's the cause of what you're seeing.

Comment: I dont think this is a correct interpretation - ILSpy regenerates C# from IL - the C# generated is functionally equivalent, but otherwise unrelated to the C# that generated the IL. Additionally the class has no base to call Finalize on so ILSpy seems to have misintepreted the code and generated non-compiling C#.

Comment: @PhillipH: You might be right - I'll dig in and update my answer.

Comment: @PhillipH: It's indeed in the raw IL, a call to Object.Finalize().

Comment: @PhillipH: Much appreciated!

Comment: now ILSpy shows destructor instead of  Finalize(), but the underlying IL code is the same